# How can I create a C++ class to perform same calculations based on different similar classes?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Probably my title is a bit vague, and that's because I don't know exactly how it is called what I want to achieve (so you are welcome to suggest a title improvement). However, look at the following code sample.

I have some classes (aSumSub, bSumSub, ... xSumSub) that they are similar. Actually the have exactly the same variables and functions but they are implemented in different ways.

I want to create another class (SumSub) which will be doing some calculations based on any of these xSumSub classes. The functions doing these additional calculations are results1, results2.. etc.

How can I implement this in an efficient way? The simplest way would be to copy the class SumSub, give it a different name and simply change the type of variable "x" and the Constructor. However, this would require me to copy a few hundreds of lines of code over and over, just for changing a couple of lines to make it compatible with all of the xSumSub functions.

There must be a cleaner way!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Class a
// I am not allowed to modify this
class aSumSub {
public:   
   int sum(){
    return 10+1;
   }

   int sub(){
    return 10-1;
   }
};

// Class b which has EXACTLY the same types of functions and variables as Class a has, but it's different implementation.
// I am not allowed to modify this
class bSumSub {
public:   
   int sum(){
    return 20+1;
   }

   int sub(){
    return 20-1;
   }
};

// Here we could have class cSumSub, ..... xSumSub etc.
// Not allowed to modify either.


// The following Class SumSub is doing some calculations that they are based on the output of the functions of the xSumSub classes.
// That's the one I want to create
class SumSub {
public:
   bSumSub *x; // <- How can I make this variable to be either of type bSumSub or aSumSub or xSumSub?

   SumSub(bSumSub *ssclass){ // And consequently, how can I have the constructor accepting either bSumSub or a aSumSub or xSumSub?
    x = ssclass;
   }

   // The rest of the functions should't need any modification
   // because we know that *x will always have the same functions and the same types will always be returned.
   void result1(){
    cout << x->sum() << endl;
   }

   void result2(){
    cout << x->sub() << endl;
   }

   void result3(){
    cout << x->sum()-x->sub() << endl;
   }

   void result4(){
    cout << x->sum()+x->sub() << endl;
   }


};

int main(){
   aSumSub as;
   bSumSub bs;

   cout << "as.sum=" << as.sum() << endl;
   cout << "bs.sum=" << bs.sum() << endl;

   SumSub ss1(&bs);
   cout << endl << "SumSub" << endl;
   ss1.result1();
   ss1.result2();
   ss1.result3();
   ss1.result4();

   // I would like to be able to do the following as well
   //SumSub ss2(&as);
   //cout << endl << "SumSub" << endl;
   //ss2.result();
   //ss2.result1();
   //ss2.result2();
   //ss2.result3();
   //ss2.result4();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use templates. Here's the templated `SumSub`.

```
template <typename T> class SumSub {
public:
   T *x;

   SumSub(T *ssclass){
    x = ssclass;
   }

   void result1(){
    cout << x->sum() << endl;
   }

   void result2(){
    cout << x->sub() << endl;
   }

   void result3(){
    cout << x->sum()-x->sub() << endl;
   }

   void result4(){
    cout << x->sum()+x->sub() << endl;
   }


};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a template:

```
template <typename BumStub>
struct SumSub
{
    using type = BumStub;

    type * x;

    SumSub(type * p) : x(p) { }

    void result1() { std::cout << x->sum() << std::endl; }

    // etc.
}
```

Usage:

```
aSumSub as;
SumSub<aSumSub> ss1(&as);
ss1.result1();
```